# Stop auto-refresh in grid view checkbox in ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GdDetails" runat="server" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
     Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Font-Size="10pt" 
     Height="72px" Width="440px" 
     ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMPDT" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMBRN" HeaderText="Branch" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMPOL" HeaderText="Policy Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMSEQ" HeaderText="DebitNote Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMDEP" HeaderText="Department" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMTOT" HeaderText="Total in Rs.">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMBAL" HeaderText="Balance in Rs.">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RECNAME" HeaderText="Name"> </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PMVE2" HeaderText="vehicleNo"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Settlement Amount" ItemStyle-Width="150">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">  
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkcsec" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="GetSelectedRecord" AutoPostBack="true"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried to used update panel it gives error unknown command. And I tried with `autopostback = false` but I need that function to fill checkbox. I want to stop code refreshing always when I TIK on check box

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide if you want code behind to run for that check box, or not?

since the check box has a onchanged event, then you NEED the auto post-back to run that code behind. if you remove the autopost back for the check box, then the check box will not work.

And you hvae to determine if the problem is that the gv refreshes anyway? Maybe it not a issue?

However, yes, surrounding the gv inside of update panel is one way to deal with this issue. It REALLY comes down to what the code for the check box is supposed to do?

And are you using a edit template for this gv? (I tend to suggest NOT using the built in editor for each row - better to separate that code out, and there are  good number of ways to achieve that goal.

A update panel will at least "appear" to not re-fresh the page, but with that post-back for the checkbox, it going to do a refresh anyway - just not the whole page.

but, do keep in mind that a update panel does NOT prevent trigger of the page load event each time. So, it is possible that the on-load event of the page has code that is messing this up. (does it have/use a if Not IsPostback code stub? (it REALLY needs one if not).

So, it not clear what/why the unknown command crops up by introduction of a update panel, but I would consider fixing that error, and thus you can keep the check box post-back code. It really depends on what the check box code (code behind does that will much determine your best course of action here).